# Android : File content can not update

Tags: java, android

I want to update a index file via the code below(in Android), but things turn out to be weird. This code can successfully print success log info, but the data file reminds the old one.

Note that, the first index data file was also created by the same code.

```
public static void updateIndexedDocumentsRecords(HashSet<String> latestDocuments) {
    try {
      // file path : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.searcher/files/indexed_documents_record
      File file = new File(MainActivity.APP_DATA_DIR + INDEXED_DOCUMENTS_RECORD_FILE);
      if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
      }
      if (latestDocuments != null && !latestDocuments.isEmpty()) {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, false);
        for (String d : latestDocuments) {
          writer.write(d);
          writer.write('\n');
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
      }
      Log.d(TAG, "update index documents record file successfully!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: does it print when you put log statements inside for-loop? Your success log info can print without executing the codes inside the for-loop.

Comment: 'file.createNewFile();'. Remove that statement. It serves nothing.

Comment: How did you check that the data remains the old one?

Comment: @greenapps I've backup the previous one and then run the app.

Comment: @user1506104 You are right, I'll try to add more log info here.